# Storing dynamic fields in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Django's form library has a feature of form sets that allow you to process dynamically added forms.  For example you would use form sets if your application has a list of bookmarks you could use form sets to process multiple forms that each represent a bookmark.

What about if you want to dynamically add a field to a form?  An example would be a survey creation page where you can dynamically add an unlimited number of questions.  How do you handle this in Django?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this recent post by Jacob Kaplan-Moss, one of the original founders of Django: ["Dynamic form generation"](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/). It uses an example to show you the process step by step. Great read.

There is also [a 2008 article by James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/), Django's release manager.

Answer (score 5):

To add, remove and change fields on a Form or ModelForm, just override `__init__()` like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    other_stuff = kwargs.pop('stuff')

    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['my_dynamic_field'] = forms.Field(...)

    # Add fields based on user or other_stuff
```

And use it like this: `form = MyForm(user = user, stuff = stuff)`

Comment: Note: I can´t send the user kwarg to super __init__ ; raise "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'"

Comment: Solved: kwargs.pop must come before super call

Answer (score 5):

In python you can instantiate a class dynamically. knutin shows a good example of dynamically customizing a form based, and adding a few fields.

You may also create the whole form dynamically, as taken from the [example given by James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/):

```
def make_contact_form(user):
    fields = { 'name': forms.CharField(max_length=50),
           'email': forms.EmailField(),
           'message': forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea) }
    if not user.is_authenticated():
    fields['captcha'] = CaptchaField()
    return type('ContactForm', (forms.BaseForm,), { 'base_fields': fields })
```