# Django form placeholder request.user

Tags: django, forms

My view:

```
form1 = UserProfile(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
```

My form:

```
class UserProfile(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user")
        super(UserProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': self.user.first_name }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': self.user.last_name }))
```

> NameError at /settings/
>   name 'self' is not defined
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/settings/
```

> Django Version:   1.5.2 Exception Type:   NameError Exception Value:   name
>   'self' is not defined

I tried to find solutions so far, and so far I came up with these codes then still in error.

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace, please?

Comment: what's a stacktrace? sorry, i'm still very new to stackoverflow. i just registered because of this one problem i cannot solve. I was just hoping to find a solution to my problem where I'd get to be able to make my placeholder display from what's inside the request.user object

Comment: You need to indent the class code.

Comment: I already did man but the error is coming from field definition. And it seems that it's already been answered down below. But thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `self` in your form field definitions since `self` variable is only available in the methods.

Your fields are dynamic and depends on the `user` variable passed in the constructor. Define your dynamic fields in `__init__.py` there you have `self.user`:

```
class UserProfile(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user")
        super(UserProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['first_name'] = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': self.user.first_name }))
        self.fields['last_name'] = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': self.user.last_name }))
```

Also see:

- [Storing dynamic fields in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506136/storing-dynamic-fields-in-django-forms)
- [Dynamic form generation](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/)

Comment: thanks man! I'm sorry for asking this dumb question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I got the answer!

    self.fields['first_name'] = forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': user.first_name }))