# Storing dynamic data in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

So, in my application I currently am receiving and storing some data,the structure currently is based around this:

- Each application has a number of devices
- Each device has incoming data from its sensors
- Each sensor has a type (e.g. temperature/humidity/etc)

Initially, I had wanted to find a solution to store the data dynamically into one table for all data, with a model that might look like this:

```
time = models.DateTimeField()
sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data = ???
```

Now, each sensor is connected in the models to all the details (including the application, the sensor hardware information and other API-related information for connecting to said sensors), however, for the data I looked up a number of options but I have yet to find one that feels sufficient, some of the options I explored are:

1. Storing the data in a dictionary and storing that in a model as per the answers in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402217/how-to-store-a-dictionary-on-a-django-model)
2. Having separate tables and somehow calling the models later when storing data using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string), in addition to some system with inheritance such as discussed [here](https://dev.to/zachtylr21/model-inheritance-in-django-m0j)
3. Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506136/storing-dynamic-fields-in-django-forms) using dynamic fields

I am currently using mySQL, and I saw some other solutions that might work using PostgreSQL for example, but I would like to avoid switching databases if there is another option.

I just feel there must be a better more clean solution for this, as it feels like a straightforward implementation. In a sense most of those implementation either feel too hack-y and inefficient especially considering that I will be storing a large amount of data (A larger number of sensors sending data continuously to the server), or do not allow queries on the sub-data.

Are there any other better implementations for my application? If not, which one of those implementations is best for me to focus on?

Comment: By PostgreSQL do you mean the `JSONField`? You can now use that in other databases also if you use Django version >= 3.1. See [`JSONField` (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield). Anyway the other solutions are not exactly hacky, considering we are talking about RDBMS. Your use case is more suited to some NoSQL database.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I read that you can store objects with postgreSQL instead, but JSONField was one of the other options.

Comment: Storing objects with PostgreSQL **is** using `JSONField` (or `HStoreField`). The other option you talk about is most likely using a `CharField` whose data you yourself convert to and from JSON...

Comment: I see, I apologize for my confusion, still a bit new in Django. So wouldn't using JSONFields be inefficient if I have to query a lot of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I ended up using, if anyone faces a similar issue, is as follows:

The main model:

```
class Sensor(Device):
    sensorName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sensorSerial = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sensorTable = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Each sensor will recieve data, each entry of said data will be saved as follows:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

And each entry will contain a number of fields which are unknown, depending on what kind of sensor it was, so a third class for the DATA is included and used a pseudo-dictionary:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I am still investigating how to push the effieciency higher, but this is definitely much faster than looping through entries while decoding XML/JSON over 100s of thousands of entries.

I will update the answer with any breakthroughs or updates I find.